# Hiding the <p> and showing the <textarea> on a <a> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know the title sounds quite easy but the real problem is the markup. I have a link in a div which also in another div but the textarea and the paragraph are in another div so that's why I am having problem on how to show and hide elements in a completely different markuped div from a completely different markuped div.

I saw [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). But they couldn't help me or I think that I was not able to take help of those.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/SZUT8/).

Here is the JS I tried:

```
$(".no_link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".edit_offer").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().children("textarea").toggle();
});
```

Comment: You can try giving your textarea an ID... and manipulate with it..

Comment: Thanks but @j08691 gave me a more good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use these selectors, but it will rely on the class `username` being in the heirarchy as you have in your code:

```
$(".edit_offer").on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.username').find("textarea").toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SZUT8/3/)**

`.closest()` will traverse up the DOM until it hits the element with class `username`, then `.find()` will go down through the children looking for the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using `find()`. http://jsfiddle.net/SZUT8/2/ To make the script more accurate and future-proof you could consider adding a class to the paragraph and matching it, as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZUT8/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign an **ID** (or a **class**, for multiple) to each of the desired elements ("p" and "textarea" in your case). Then use your ID/class to reference them for the `show()` or `hide()` methods, rather than navigating the DOM via `parent()`, `sibling()` and `children()`.

Then your click handler will only need the line:

`$('#idOfElement).toggle();`