# Toggling one thing with two different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231927/hiding-the-p-and-showing-the-textarea-on-a-a-click) I asked about how can I toggle a textarea with a paragraph. I got the answer. Now I want to do the opposite of it. First I was showing the already hidden textarea + 2 buttons by a click of a hyperlink. Now on the click of one of the buttons I want to hide the text + 2 buttons and show the paragraph that was first already shown.

I have tried this JS so far but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".no_link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".edit_offer").on('click', function () {
        toggleEditPanel($(this));
    });
    $("#cancel_edits").on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest("button").hide();
        $(this).closest("textarea").hide();
        $(this).closest("p.content").show();
    });
});

function toggleEditPanel(link) {
    link.parent().parent().parent().find("textarea").toggle();
    link.parent().parent().parent().find("button").toggle();
    link.parent().parent().parent().find("p.content").toggle();
}
```

But its not working. How can I solve this error?

If I am trying to call the function `toggleEditPanel()` again. Its not working then aswell.

*You can find the markup in the fiddle. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/SZUT8/5/).*

**UPDATE 1:**

Just came up with a solution. I can use the `$.siblings()` function to toggle the elements beside the button. Still, is there any better solution?

Here's the code that I came up with:

```
$("#cancel_edits").on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings("button").hide();
    $(this).siblings("textarea").hide();
    $(this).siblings("p.content").show();
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem in the above code is that if there are more than one panels like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/SZUT8/9/) then the code is not working. How can I solve that issue aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Id for selector $("#cancel_edits") .
Id selectors returns only first element , so if there are multiple pannel it will work only for first.

Instead give some class name and use it for selector. Further you can use chaining and caching in your code for better performance.

```
$(".cancel_edits").on('click', function () {
    var elm=$(this);
    elm.add(elm.siblings("button,textarea")).hide();
    elm.siblings("p.content").show();
});
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Here, I made it: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/SZUT8/10/. You code still don't work. :/

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the fiddle. Your code is working. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend referencing your elements by ID:

```
$("#cancel_edits").on('click', function () {
    $('#save_edits').hide();
    $('#edited_content').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $("p.content").show();
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZUT8/8/)**</kbd>

The great thing about using IDs is that you are *guaranteed* they are unique - no need to use `closest()` to find the element you want. If, however, you're using classes instead, `closest()` might be necessary or helpful.

Comment: But I think that using `siblings` could become more specific and will be easy to use when I will add some more elements in the panel.

Comment: Siblings works too. But from what you provided us, IDs would be just as feasible. `siblings()` is great for when you don't want to reference an element by ID, which it seems like you'd want to do if you recycle this code.

Comment: And if there are more than one panels like http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/SZUT8/9/ then your code is not working neither mine.